# Find intermediate color

Tags: colors

I have 2 colors #DCE7FA and #CADBF7. Want the intermediate color(a kind of Arithmetic mean).

Hexadecimal arithmetic median does not work.

How to proceed?

Comment: What is an "intermediate color"? With your example, what would that be and how would you arrive at it?

Comment: @Oded, if you want a "Arithmetic mean" between them.

Comment: As raj noted, RGB values are composed from components, so you need to get the mean for each component and recombine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the normal hex median wont work.. !!
try spliting to to R, G , B and find individual medians..

```
r1 = DC ; r2 = CA  
g1 = E7 ; g2 = DB  
b1 = FA ; b2 = F7
```

now find individual medians..

now,

```
r3 = (r1+r2)/2 = D3 ;  
g3 = E1  
b3 = F5
```

now ur intermediate color  = `#D3E1F5..`

Comment: not good: see
http://www.colortools.net/color_compare_colors.html 
visually `(#DCE7FA + #CADBF7) / 2 != #ABCDEF`

Comment: @seriho.. i gave an EXAMPLE on how to split to RGB and find individial medians,, now i took my time and calculated the actual values and re-posted.. check it now..

Comment: and again : the median of colores SHOULD NOT be calculated as `(HexColor1 + HexColor2)/2` . Its calculated as the median of individual channels like i said in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found an online tool: 
http://www.colortools.net/color_combination.html

Comment: That combines (finds the actual `(HexColor1 + HexColor2)/2`),  guess thats not you want.. This type of finding mean is not at all reccomended.. even in one channel (say grayscale) coloring, they make `(color1+color2)%255` [note they take the remainder with the maximum color.]